# Psycopg2 to create a record using a foreign key

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running the following versions of software:

```
Python 3.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
Postgres 9.4.5
```

I have 2 tables.  Table `User` has `UserId (serial PK)`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, `Gender`, `DateOfBirth`, and `DateEnrolled`.  Table `UserProfile` has `UserProfileId (serial, PK)`, `UserId (FK)`, `DateEntered`, `FaveNumber`, and `Activity`.  There is a one-to-many relationship.

The following PostgreSQL works and ultimately creates a record in UserProfile with an associated UserId (FK).

```
\set last_name '''Sara'''
\set first_name '''Jackson'''
\set gender '''F'''
\set dob '''1941-1-12'''
\set fave_number '''3''' 
\set activity '''volleyball'''


WITH ins_user AS (
INSERT INTO User
(LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, DateEnrolled)
VALUES (:last_name, :first_name, :gender, :dob, now())
RETURNING UserId)
INSERT INTO UserProfile
(UserId, DateEntered, FaveNumber, Activity) 
VALUES ( (SELECT UserId FROM ins_user), now(), :fave_number :activity);
```

How can I build a psycopg2 cur.execute query that will accomplish the above PostgreSQL?  I've read documentation but can't seem to get a handle on how I should structure this command.

My starting point is:

```
cur.execute( \
"""INSERT INTO User \
(LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, DateEnrolled) \
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING UserId;""", \
(last_name, first_name, gender, date_of_birth, now(), ??...??)
```

In addition, is it possible to extract that value derived from `RETURNING UserId` so that it can be used in a later query?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clearer to use a dictionary to pass the parameters

```
ins = """
    with ins_user as (
        insert into User (
            LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, DateEnrolled
        ) values (%(last_name)s, %(first_name)s, %(gender)s, %(dob)s, now())
        returning UserId
    )
    insert into UserProfile (
        UserId, DateEntered, FaveNumber, Activity
    ) values ((select UserId from ins_user), now(), %(fave_number)s, %(activity)s)
"""

ins_dict = dict (
    last_name = 'Sara',
    first_name = 'Jackson',
    gender = 'F',
    dob = '1941-1-12',
    fave_number = '3',
    activity = 'volleyball'
)
print cur.mogrify(ins, ins_dict) # inspect the rendered command
cur.execute(ins, ins_dict)
connection.commit()
```

If `DateEnrolled` will always receive `now()` then make it the default

```sql
DateEnrolled date default now(),
```

Comment: > Thanks for the response.  I didn't know I could pass a dictionary as an argument into cur.execute.
+1 for setting date now() as default in the table!

Answer (score -2):

```
cur.execute( \
"""INSERT INTO User \
(LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, DateEnrolled) \
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING UserId;""", \
(last_name, first_name, gender, date_of_birth, now(), ??...??)
```